# Giving an IAM user, permission to a specific folder of a bucket in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am stuck in writing a policy,

Scenario: We have a bucket called BUCKET, and there are two folders, FOLDER1 and FOLDER2 inside it. Now there is one IAM USER, user1. This user should have read/write access to FOLDER1 but not any access in FOLDER2. And user should also able able to list the Folders inside BUCKET. Means user should able to see the folder in which it have the permission.

Any lead will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a bucket policy with the exact path you want to give access to like below,

```js
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddCannedAcl", //Here add your Sid
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root","arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"]}, //Here add you users ARN
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/YOUR FOLDER/*"] //Here
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the sample policies mentioned in this blogpost will meet your requirement:
[Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)